# Mysql queries inside controller class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Usetable contains username and password fields and inserted one value to that table

username:admin
password:text
In view file contains text boxes for username and password and a login button  as follows.

```
<%= form_tag(:action =>"login", :method => "post", :id=>"frm") do %>

User Name:<%= text_field_tag(:username) %>
Password:<%= text_field_tag(:password) %>
<%= button_to("login ", :class=>"btn") %>
<% end %>
```

if the enterd username and password is same as the data present in the usertable redirct to home page other wise login is not succesful

What i want is 
while clicking on the login button pass the username text and password text to controller
 execute a mysql query like `select * from usertable where uername=** and password=**`

I dont know how to write mysql query inside controller method.How it is possible?
my controller class looks like

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

      def home
        @username=params[:username]
        @password=params[:password]

   # here i have to write that query.#


render :action => :home
  end
end
```

Iam using rails 3

Comment: As a side comment you should not be storing plain passwords in the DB but I'm sure you know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `@user = User.where(:username => params[:username], :password => params[:password])`